# How to put conditional job in need of another job in Github Action

Tags: github-actions

Below is my GitHub workflow

```
name: APP Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/test

jobs:
  test-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains( github.event.head_commit.message, 'test1') }}
    steps:
      - name: test-fail
        run: echo "test1"
  test-2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains( github.event.head_commit.message, 'test2') }}
    steps:
      - name: test-fail
        run: echo "test1"
  notify-slack:
    name: Slack Notification
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [test-1, test-2]
    steps:
      - name: Slack Notification
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.2.0
        env:
          SLACK_CHANNEL: alert
          SLACK_COLOR: "${{ job.status == 'success' && 'good' || 'danger' }}"
```

Question: `test1` and `test2` job is conditional as per my commit message but notify slack need either `test1` or `test2`. I can't put both because if either the job skip `notify-slack` will skip as well. How to make this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an issue on [Github about this](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/491#issuecomment-850884422). You need to add condition like below:

```yaml
  test-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains( github.event.head_commit.message, 'test1') }}
    steps:
      - name: test-fail
        run: echo "test1"
  test-2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains( github.event.head_commit.message, 'test2') }}
    steps:
      - name: test-fail
        run: echo "test1"
  notify-slack:
    name: Slack Notification
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [test-1, test-2]
    if: |
      always() && 
      (needs.test-1.result == 'success' || needs.test-1.result == 'skipped') && 
      (needs.test-2.result == 'success' || needs.test-2.result == 'skipped') && 
      !(needs.test-1.result == 'skipped' && needs.test-2.result == 'skipped')
    steps:
      - name: Slack Notification
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.2.0
        env:
          SLACK_CHANNEL: alert
          SLACK_COLOR: "${{ job.status == 'success' && 'good' || 'danger' }}"
```

Comment: tried this but getting error "You have an error in your yaml syntax on line"

    if: |
    always() &&
    (needs.check-environment.result == 'success' || needs.check-environment.result == 'skipped') &&
    (needs.deploy.result == 'success' || needs.deploy.result == 'skipped') &&
    (needs.restart-pods.result == 'success' || needs.restart-pods.result == 'skipped') &&
    (github.event_name == 'pull_request')

Comment: The above condition is now working. The first two conditions are working fine. if either of the jobs is a success then we have to build but if both job skip then skip the build but this condition is not correctly working
(needs.test-1.result != 'skipped' && needs.test-2.result != 'skipped')

Comment: You are right I changed condition. `(needs.test-1.result == 'success' || needs.test-2.result == 'success')` so know it shoudl fire when one of is `success` or `skipped` but will not fire when none of the is `success`. Is this expected bahavior? Or we should also fire this step when both are skipped?

Comment: I modified the condition and now it's working. Please update this in your answer.
      always() &&
      (needs.test-1.result == 'success' || needs.test-1.result == 'skipped') &&
      (needs.test-2.result == 'success' || needs.test-2.result == 'skipped') && !(needs.test-1.result == 'skipped' && needs.test-2.result == 'skipped')

Comment: I updated my reply. I'm glad you found finally solution for your issue!

Comment: Is there another approach since adding more jobs will result in having a lot of conditions ?

Comment: I took a look at the linked GitHub issue. And since it is still open and in further comments, there is no better approach I doubt that it could be solved in another way.

Answer (score 4):

**Implementation such condition can be achieved by using following workflow logic**

```yaml
jobs:
  A:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "success always"
  B:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: false
    steps:
      - run: echo "this will never run"
  C:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          exho "here to fail"
          exit 1

  D:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [A, B, C]
    if: |
      always() &&
      !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')
    # you can add conditions if needed e.g.
    # !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure')
    steps:
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(needs) }}"
```

Your need to modify also your `SLACK_COLOR` logic. `job.status == 'success'` will not work since it will always be `success` for this job regardless did any of the dependencies failed. Use `needs` for your logic e.g. job `D` output is:

```js
{
  A: {
    result: success,
    outputs: {}
  },
  B: {
    result: skipped,
    outputs: {}
  },
  C: {
    result: failure,
    outputs: {}
  }
}
```

so you `SLACK_COLOR` could be set like this

```yaml
SLACK_COLOR: "${{ contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') && 'danger' || 'good' }}"
```

Comment: if: |
      always() &&
      !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')

but with this condition, if C failed then also it will run because we are using always()?

Comment: That is correct if you want exclude execution of `D` when `C` or any dependencies fail use this if condition for `D` `always() && !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') && !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')`